# Matlab Time-varying covariance matrix loop

Tags: matlab, matrix, conditional-statements, covariance

I have a portfolio with assets and I like to calculate the variance of the portfolio. I calculated the weights of the assets and the covariance matrix. Both are time-varying. To get the variance I need the formula below:

Wt'*SIGMA_1*Wt = variance portfolio

In Matlab I used the following code to calculate the weight of each asset:

```
for t=1:n
    At_1(:,t)    = inv(SIGMA_1(:,:,t))*FIT_1';
    Wt_1(t,1)    = At_1(1,t)/sum(At_1(:,t));
    Wt_1(t,2)    = At_1(2,t)/sum(At_1(:,t));
    Wt_1(t,3)    = At_1(3,t)/sum(At_1(:,t));
    Wt_1(t,4)    = At_1(4,t)/sum(At_1(:,t));
    Wt_1(t,5)    = At_1(5,t)/sum(At_1(:,t));
    Wt_1(t,6)    = At_1(6,t)/sum(At_1(:,t));
    Wt_1(t,7)    = At_1(7,t)/sum(At_1(:,t));
    Wt_1(t,8)    = At_1(8,t)/sum(At_1(:,t));
    Wt_1(t,9)    = At_1(9,t)/sum(At_1(:,t));
    Wt_1(t,10)    = At_1(10,t)/sum(At_1(:,t));


end
```

where SIGMA_1 is the covariance matrix. 
Now I need a loop to calculate the time-varying variance of the portfolio. I have 10 time-varying weights, and the time-varying covariance SIGMA_1.I am stuck with writing a loop for that. Can somebody help me with this?

Comment: Being stuck is not really a good description of what is going wrong. Maybe you can compile an example that is fully self-contained.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

```
 for t=1:n
    At_1(:,t)    = inv(SIGMA_1(:,:,t))*FIT_1';

    for k=1:10
       Wt_1(t,k)    = At_1(k,t)/sum(At_1(:,t)); 
    end
 end
```